# Split Table by months in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple table where all the datas are generated automatically. What i want was i want to separate the table by months. It should in descending order. Tables are separated by the Month names followed by the year.

I have created a fiddle to help you out. Thanks!
**Fiddle:**
https://fiddle.jshell.net/Hive/cv3c0md2/

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>28 may 2016</td>
        <td>sometext</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>23 may 2016</td>
        <td>sometext</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>16 jun 2016</td>
        <td>sometext</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>20 jun 2016</td>
        <td>sometext</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to split by months. Like this

```
<h4>May 2016</h4>
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>28 may 2016</td>
        <td>sometext</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>23 may 2016</td>
        <td>sometext</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<h4>Jun 2016</h4>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>18 jun 2016</td>
        <td>sometext</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>16 jun 2016</td>
        <td>sometext</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>01 jun 2016</td>
        <td>sometext</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<h4>Dec 2016</h4>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>18 dec 2016</td>
        <td>sometext</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @AshboDev Sorry for the delay. i tried with .split method but i don't know how to get the table to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the original rows are moved to its corresponding table, you don't have to worry about adding extra columns to the table later on. 
Moving the rows with jQuery can be done by appending them to another table.

You mentioned sorting, so the below takes into account that the source table is not in the proper sorting order. (If it already is, the mapping could be skipped and thus the code could be shortened somewhat):

```
var table= $('table'),  //might need a more specific selector if there are more tables
    rows = table.find('tr').remove().map(function(ind,tr ){ //Note the remove. While obtaining the rows, they are also removed from the original table
        var d = new Date($(tr).children('td:first').text());
        return {Row:tr, Date: d, yearMonth : d.getYear() * 100 + d.getMonth()}; //create a mapping of the table row, its date and the month (+year to be safe)
    }).get(),
  curym,
  monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
rows.sort(function(r1,r2) { return (r1.yearMonth - r2.yearMonth) || r2.Date - r1.Date ; }) //sort so that months are ascending and inner dates are descending. 
    .forEach(function(o){
    if(o.yearMonth != curym){ //another month
    if(curym)table = $('<table>').appendTo(table.parent()); //only start a new table on a second run, otherwise reuse existing table
    curym = o.yearMonth;
    $('<h4>').text(monthNames[curym % 100]).insertBefore(table); //insert the header
  }
  table.append(o.Row);
});
```

Implemented in your fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/cv3c0md2/4/ (example fiddle also contains 2 times on the same date to show they are sorted)

Comment: Is it possible to keep the implementation to 5, iam new to javascript this thing will go above my head. Will this work if i implement the time next to the date like (15:30, 18:25, 23:40..)

Comment: The ES6 features should be removed in the edit. Adding of a time shouldn't be a problem as long as the contents form a format that can be parsed to a date(time). In the example fiddle I've added a time as an example. If the times are added to a separate column they won't interfere at all, but then they won't be included in the descending sort

Answer (score 1):

Hey i have created a jsfiddle for the same and i am assuming the main table from which the child tables will be create is already sorted.

JSFiddle:-https://fiddle.jshell.net/cv3c0md2/1/

Code:-

```
 var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
      "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
  ];

  function createRow(row, tr) {
      $('<td></td>').text(row.find("td:eq(0)").text()).appendTo(tr);
      $('<td></td>').text(row.find("td:eq(1)").text()).appendTo(tr);
      $('<td></td>').text(row.find("td:eq(2)").text()).appendTo(tr);
  }

  function createTables() {
      var lastMonth;
      $.each($("table").find("td:nth-child(1)"), function(index, td) {
          var row = $(td).closest("tr");
          var d = new Date($(td).text());
          var table = $("<table />");
          var tr = $("<tr></tr>");

          if (lastMonth && lastMonth === d.getMonth()) {
              $(".result").find("table:last").append(tr);
              createRow(row, tr);
          } else {
              var h = $("<h/>");
              h.text(monthNames[d.getMonth()] + "  " + d.getFullYear());
              table.append(tr);
              createRow(row, tr);
              $(".result").append("<br/>")
              $(".result").append(h);
              $(".result").append(table);
              lastMonth = d.getMonth();
          }
      });
  }
  $(function() {

      $("#ds").click(function() {
          createTables();
      });
  });
```

In this you need to click on split button and it will convert the one table into multiple tables and you can modify it as per your need.

Comment: This is great, but how do i apply this to table without using the button. I want to display the table with month and year once the user lands on the page.

Comment: call "createTables" methodss on load directly in place of click button. accept answer if it works for you